# Find the kernel structure that contains device name

Tags: windows, windbg, kernel-mode

I'm using WinDbg to try enumerate drivers and their associated devices. Getting the driver name is very easy. It is found in the [_DRIVER_OBJECT](http://msdn.moonsols.com/win7rtm_x86/DRIVER_OBJECT.html) structure. Unfortunately, the [_DEVICE_OBJECT](http://msdn.moonsols.com/win7rtm_x86/DEVICE_OBJECT.html) does not contain the name of the device.

Using the `!devobj` command I can see the name of the device, but I would like to find the table/structure that contains the name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So assuming like you said, you have the linear address of your device object, use the windbg extension `!object 0xlinearaddress`. Based on your windows build, it will display the linear address of the object header. Which in memory exists right below the object.

Use windbg to parse the `OBJECT_HEADER` structure for you. Starting with Windows 7 you are going to have a member called `InfoMask`, earlier versions have `NameInfoOffset`.

If you have an earlier build, `NameInfoOffset` is subtracted from the linear base of the object header, to get you the base of an `OBJECT_HEADER_NAME_INFO` structure for that object.

If you have a Windows 7 build or later, `InfoMask` is a bitmask describing other creator structures that exist before the beginning of the header. It is computed using the `ObInfoMaskToOffsetTable` which contains the offset to the `OBJECT_HEADER_NAME_INFO` structure for the object. It is always at a constant location but the `InfoMask` should be used to determine if the object is named, because not all objects are required to be named.

So a quick example for you, let's say you have a device object at `fffffa8001234560`. Let's also presume you are using Windows 7 x64.

Your name info would be:

```
dt nt!_object_header_name_info fffffa8001234560-0x30-0x20
```

-0x30 to base of header
-0x20 because in this case `InfoMask` used in the table has an index value of 0x20.

This structure contains the name **relative** to it's object directory.

Also have a look at the exported kernel routine `ObQueryNameInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember, both XP and Win7 always had this format:

`object_directory_followed` by `object_header` whose `_QUAD` part (opaque do not use this field) points to the `OBJECT`

If you did `dt nt!_Object_header_name_info <address of object> - 0x28`:

```
kd> !devobj \Device\Beep;dt nt!_OBJECT_HEADER_NAME_INFO 86884db8-28
Device object (86884db8) is for:
 Beep \Driver\Beep DriverObject 86e703b8
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000001 Flags 00000044
Dacl e1020c34 DevExt 86884e70 DevObjExt 86884ec8 
ExtensionFlags (0000000000)  
Device queue is not busy.
   +0x000 Directory        : 0xe100d670 _OBJECT_DIRECTORY
   +0x004 Name             : _UNICODE_STRING "Beep"
   +0x00c QueryReferences  : 1
kd> !devobj \Device\00000013
Device object (86fe7cd0) is for:
 00000013 \Driver\PnpManager DriverObject 86fe9328
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000004 Flags 00001040
Dacl e1020c34 DevExt 86fe7d88 DevObjExt 86fe7d90 DevNode 86fe7b88 
ExtensionFlags (0x00000010)  DOE_START_PENDING
Device queue is not busy.
kd> dt nt!_OBJECT_HEADER_NAME_INFO 86fe7cd0-28
   +0x000 Directory        : 0xe100d670 _OBJECT_DIRECTORY
   +0x004 Name             : _UNICODE_STRING "00000013"
   +0x00c QueryReferences  : 1
```